# Infragistics ultrawebgrid v11.1 compatible issue in Internet explorer 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, infragistics

Infragistics Ultrawebgrid v11 does not seems to be working on internet explorer 11.

This tool works perfectly in Mozilla and chrome but in IEv11 infragistics is completely broken.

Though it does work well in comptability mode of IE. I have tried by adding the following meta header but no luck

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />.
```

I know this is older version of infragistics but I can't update the infragistics immediately so need help how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it is the same issue, but I found that some browsers were being auto-detected as Down-Level, causing the grid to become unusable (I think some of the grid Javascript wasn't being loaded).

Try adding Browser="UpLevel" to your UltraWebGrid tag.

For example:

```
<igtbl:ultrawebgrid id="UltraWebGrid1" Browser="UpLevel" runat="server"...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your infragistics controls. There are service releases that fixes most problems with ie 11.

you can do it by loggin on to your account on infragistics.

Comment: Hey ArchLight. I was going through the infragistics support blogs to see how can i upgrade to higher version but found they have remove the classic asp.net controls ULTRAWEBGRID from v11.2. I believe new webgrid control will work with same logic. will it ?. could you please suggest how can i run my infragistics ultrawebgrid on IE 11. Here is the link http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/62373.aspx

Comment: If you haven't downloaded the latest service release of NetAdvantage for ASP.NET 2011 Volume 1, you could also test that to see if it resolves any of the issues you are seeing.  Other than that your best options are to continue to use IE10, use compatibility mode in IE11 if it works, or migrate to the newer WebDataGrid and WebHierarchicalDataGrid.